# Python program to sort and count repeated no in list

Tags: python, list, function, sorting

Write a Python function histogram(l) that takes as input a list of integers with repetitions and returns a list of pairs as follows:
for each number n that appears in l, there should be exactly one pair (n,r) in the list returned by the function, where r is is the number of repetitions of n in l.

the final list should be sorted in ascending order by r, the number of repetitions. For numbers that occur with the same number of repetitions, arrange the pairs in ascending order of the value of the number.

For instance:

```
>>> histogram([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,7,13,14,12])
[(11, 1), (7, 2), (12, 2), (14, 2), (13, 4)]

>>> histogram([7,12,11,13,7,11,13,14,12])
[(14, 1), (7, 2), (11, 2), (12, 2), (13, 2)]

>>> histogram([13,7,12,7,11,13,14,13,7,11,13,14,12,14,14,7])
[(11, 2), (12, 2), (7, 4), (13, 4), (14, 4)]
```

Comment: To all the people answering this question: Its a request that you please consider asking the OP what he has tried and then  help him reach the appropriate solution. Because this looks like a homework problem.

Answer (score 2):

The Counter object is perfect for this.

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,7,13,14,12])
Counter({13: 4, 12: 2, 14: 2, 7: 2, 11: 1})
```

Edit:
And if you want the result in a list of tuples sorted by value, you can do the following.

```
>>> count = Counter([13,12,11,13,14,13,7,7,13,14,12])
>>> sorted(count.items(), key=lambda c: c[1])
[(11, 1), (12, 2), (14, 2), (7, 2), (13, 4)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time please share what you've tried yourself.

```
def make_histogram(lst):
    new_lst = list(set([(i, lst.count(i)) for i in lst]))
    new_lst.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
    return new_lst
```